# Output dictionary items that have a count of 1

Tags: python, dictionary

I have parsed through a number of xml files to create a dictionary that contains each word and the count of the number of times that word appears.

I would like to know the number of words that have a count of 1 in my dictionary so that I can later go replace them with a token and reduce vocab size.

I don't have the dictionary on hand, but it would look similar to:

```
vocab = {'a': 17, 'the': 15, 'skeleton': 1, 'doctor': 3, 'house': 1, 'body': 2}
```

I would like the output of to be each word that appears once and the count of how many words meet that criteria. i.e.:

```
(skeleton, house)
2
```

Comment: Can we get a snippet of the dict that holds the words and counts?

Comment: `len([1 for x in word_counts.items() if x[1] == 1])`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but using list comprehensions would be my preference. E.g., to get the list of words with a count equal to 1:

```
words = [k for (k, v) in vocab.iteritems() if v == 1]
```

And to get the count:

```
len(words)
```

Comment: Thank you, Dan. I appreciate your help!